# Calendar error in Java

Tags: java, android, calendar

I use `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance()` to store the current date. But when i try to view i find an error.

`c.get(Calendar.MONTH+1)` is egual to 49.

Why?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you think `c.get(Calendar.MONTH+1)` should return and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You passed the `+1` to the argument to `get`,

```
c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
```

will give you the `MONTH`. `Calendar.MONTH + 1` is 3 or [`Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_YEAR).

Comment: Thank you, you solve my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Calendar.MONTH is simply calling the field with respective name MONTH in the class Calendar, it is just an integer. Looking into the Calendar class (and filtering out some documentation) we can see the following defined for Calendar's `get` and `set` methods:

```
public final static int ERA = 0;
public final static int YEAR = 1;
public final static int MONTH = 2;
public final static int WEEK_OF_YEAR = 3;
public final static int WEEK_OF_MONTH = 4;
public final static int DATE = 5;
etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// using Calendar class
Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();

String CiDateTime = "" + ci.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + 
(ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" +
ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " +
ci.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" +
ci.get(Calendar.MINUTE) +  ":" +
ci.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

The output of the code above is:

2014-12-2 10:46:56

Comment: Maybe you should say, that `12` doesn't means `December`.